# EC2 SSH connection refused after changing elastic IP and reboot

Tags: ssh, ip, tcp, amazon-ec2

I've browsed several dozen copies of this question but none of them seem to fix my situation.

I have already checked:

- permissions on pem key (it worked before)
- checked correct new ip in ssh config
- checked port 22 is open in security group

Another fact is that this instance is a clone of another instance with the same vpc and same permissions, with an elastic ip which I can connect to perfectly. Removing the 22 permission in the vpc groups makes ssh return "Operation timed out" for both, then re-adding the port 22 permission back causes the original instance to connect to ssh properly, but the new one (the problematic instance) to get "Connection refused" again.

To summarize, I had a perfectly good instance which I could ssh into. I added an elastic ip (on aws and changed ssh config), rebooted it, and can no longer ssh back into it with port 22 connection refused. None of the common troubleshooting suggestions I've found in other posts have worked so far.

Comment: Just to clarify, before you changed the new ec2 to use an EIP, were you able to connect to it? Also, you said "I added an elastic ip (on aws and changed ssh config)". What ssh config did you change?

Comment: I changed the IP in the Hostname section of my config file in my .ssh folder.

Comment: As far as I can recall yes I could ssh back into it, then did a reboot, then after the reboot could not ssh back into it

Comment: Try removing the old IP Address line of the new ec2 from your `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. If you can't find it, try `mv ~/.ssh/known_hosts ~/.ssh/known_hosts.backup` and then try to connect to the new ec2 with the EIP

Comment: yep already tried this didnt work